# Solr remove quotes from multivalued value or update at once

Tags: solr, solr5

I've index data to my **SOLR** core using **CURL** command where the data was on **CSV** format. The command was `curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update?commit=true' --data-binary @my_docs.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'`

The data is imported successfully but I got an issue with **multiValued** field.
On my **.csv** file the value for the **multiValued** field was like this `"['parking','garden','spa']"` so now imported data on my solr core looks like with extra double quotes in below format.

```
"amenities": [
          "['parking', 'garden', 'spa']"
          ^                            ^
           ]
```

To remove that **double quotes** from my **multiValued** field I've tried this way from the Document section of SOLR ADMIN UI section and I succeeded to Atomic Update with this format of JSON

```
{
 "id":"2118506",
 "amenities":{"set":["parking", "garden", "spa""]},
}
```

I know I can Atomic Update all of the index document using this way by sending curl request on solr with **SET** but it is hard for me at this moment because I've 20M documents already indexed.

So I just want to know at this time is there any way I can remove the double quotes from **multiValued** field at query time or any smarter way to remove double quotes from field value with a single curl command **without specifying individual document ids**

**N.B** It is hard for me now to remove double quotes from each and every csv file and try to re-index documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the double quotes is because your value is being indexed as a string - it's not being indexed as a multivalued field. The double quotes are there since that's how JSON indicates that we're talking about a string.

You'll need to change this when indexing your data, and you can [use a few special arguments when indexing CSV](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVUpdateParameters):

```
f.amenities.split=true&f.amenities.separator=%2C
```

That way the values will be indexed as an actual multivalued field, by splitting the values from the field on `,`. If you have an actual JSON list in your CSV file, I strongly recommend removing `[`, `'` and `]` from the field as a preprocessing step.